# I cannot deployment Django 1.7 admin with apache and wsgi in Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, deployment

I'm creating a project in Django on ubuntu with apache and wsgi, I have no trouble seeing the home, but want to see the page administrator internet searches "ecomerce / admin".

I'm working with:

Django 1.7 - python 2.7 - apache2 - Ubuntu14

My code is as follows:

### /etc/apache2/sites-available/ecomerce.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ecomerce
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/ecomerce/ecomerce/wsgi.py
    <Directory /usr/var/www/ecomerce>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
    </Files>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

---

### etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1    ecomerce
```

---

### Django site:

```
           ecomerce
                   ecomerce
                              settings.py
                              urls.py
                              wsgi.py
                              __init__.py
                   manage.py
                   db.sqlite3
```

---

### wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys
path = '/var/www/ecomerce'
if path not in sys.path:
sys.path.append(path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ecomerce.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

---

### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'ecomerce.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

---

### settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for ecomerce project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '56@w10z_c&%kf3#am#1(t=!c(bsf+mq@2pa(n&i8gky43l4#7g'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ecomerce.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ecomerce.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Try set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['your.site.url']`

Comment: Try using the URL `http://ecomerce/admin/`, with a trailing slash. I've experienced problems similar to this one in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but do not answer my problem. I tried both options but none works. In fact it does not recognize the location of the file urls.py